# Getting error while servlet program HTTP Status 404

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, servlets, tomcat7, http-status-code-404

I am new to Servlets. Anyhow, My Server runs just fine, I can access my index.html and everything is working but when I try to run my servlet on the server it gives me 404 error

I tried tp restart server, edit the web.xml file but no luck, there's also some older questions on SO for the same question, but all different from my case. Tried `urlPatters{"/SimpleServlet"}` also no luck..

Running on a Linux machine with Eclipse Luna and tomcat7.

Here's my servlet

```
package com.bgt.zaa;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class SimpleServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/SimpleServlet")
public class SimpleServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }

}
```

and here's my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>SinmpleServletProject</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

The error:
[image]

Comment: Is your servlet compiled ok and its class generated?

Comment: Yes the class file is generated but still..

Answer (score 0):

Seems a typo mistake in your URL.

try this

```
127.0.0.1:8080/SimpleServletProject/SimpleServlet
```

instead of

```
127.0.0.1:8080/SinmpleServletProject/SimpleServlet
```

your 404 URL has `SinmPleServletProject`. An extra n, I guess.

HTTP 404 means, requested resource is not found. So most probably the Servlet is not started properly (or) the project context root is different.

Comment: This is the the name of project, I did a typo writing the name and didn't change it..